# What is the best way to delay re-render for controlled components in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender

Let's say I have a simple controlled input component in React.

```
const ControlledInput = () => {

    const [state, setState] = React.useState("");

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        setState(e.target.value);
    };

    return <input type="text" value={state} onChange={handleInputChange} />
};
```

So, in this simple example, the component will be re-rendered with each character user entered. What is the best experience used to delay re-render? I mean user types to the input the word " I am user " and we want that re-render to happen when the user stops entering characters or maybe after 3 seconds when the user started to type?

Comment: So you would want the user not to see what they've actually typed..?

Comment: This is a bad idea... You're over-optimizing, and it's going to hurt user experience.

Comment: Yeah you are right guys it was just an interesting but unnecessary idea  as @BrianThompson told earlier it will be better to debounce API call rather than input itself. I should've ask what are the best exeperiences in debouncing API calls which related with user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I use SetTimeout to delay a re-render, here is code example

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactElement;
  waitBeforeShow?: number;
};

const Delayed = ({ children, waitBeforeShow = 500 }: Props) => {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(waitBeforeShow);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsShown(true);
    }, waitBeforeShow);
  }, [waitBeforeShow]);

  return isShown ? children : null;
};

export default Delayed;
```

And

```
export function LoadingScreen = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Delayed>
      <div />
    </Delayed>
  );
};
```

Comment: But he doesn't want a loading screen...

Comment: You mean in animation? Please specify your case because the answer will be different in some cases ( like animations )

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in this case, would be using the `setTimeout()` method for adding some delay to the rendering of component or API calls.

***Note: In the below-shared example you should not use the `inputValue` var which I control using some delay it's sole purpose is to debounce the typing.***

This is what you will have to use `setTimeout()` in a way that it gets cleared every time the user inputs something and for that, you will need to save `setTimeout()` reference using bellow snippet

```
var timoutId = setTimeout(cb,timeout);
```

After this, you can clear the timeout by calling this `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`

I have created a short demo which worth checking out: [Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-bush-tw7mp8?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the final snippet which is used in the above mentioned sandbox:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // for preserving input value with delay
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState("");
  // to maintain the timeout ref
  let intervalId = React.useRef();
  // handle input change with delay
  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    // input box value
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(value, "value");
    // clear the existing timout
    clearTimeout(intervalId.current);
    // reassign new timout ref
    intervalId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      setValue(value);
      console.log("I'm inside the setTimeout callback function!");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input onChange={handleChange} />
      <p>{inputValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you pass `input` a `value` to make it a "controlled" input like the OP says.

Comment:  Yes @BrianThompson you are right I was not intended to use the `value` for `input` but instead, think of a case where some crazy user tries to doge with the search box which gets data from API as user type so, with every letter typed noob developer will get data from API which will be slow at some time and most important **network, resource and memory cost will be increased** results would not appear better.

Comment: Then the solution is to debounce the API request, not the input. Using a half-controlled input is just asking for bugs. The state value and the input value are now no longer guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: Hi, @BrianThompson yes that's why I have mentioned in the start of comment that value should not be used to control the input element.

Comment: That's what I'm saying I disagree with. You *should* use the value to control the input, and use other means to limit API requests/etc.

Comment: Hi, @BrianThompson I have mentioned a note in my answer to be more clear to the users/visitors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242524/discussion-between-ali-hussnain-and-brian-thompson).